# How to update an existing Blob in Azure Storage in .NET 6 or in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have prepared some C# code to create a container in the Azure Storage and then I am uploading a file into that azure container. The code is below:

```
var connectionString = _settings.appConfig.StorageConnectionString;
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

BlobContainerClient blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("nasir-container");            
await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(); // Create the container.

BlobClient blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName); // Creating the blob

string fileName = "D:/Workspace/Adappt/MyWordFile.docx";
FileStream uploadFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName);
blobClient.Upload(uploadFileStream);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Now I have updated my **MyWordFile.docx** with more content. Now I would like to upload this updated file to the same blob storage. How can I do this? I also want to create versioning too so that I can get the file content based on the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I have updated my MyWordFile.docx with more content. Now I would
> like to upload this updated file to the same blob storage. How can I
> do this?

To update a blob, you simply upload the same file (basically use the same code you wrote to upload the file in the first place). Upload operation will overwrite an existing blob.

> I also want to create versioning too so that I can get the file
> content based on the version.

There are two ways you can implement versioning for blobs:

1. **Automatic versioning**: If you want Azure Blob Storage service to maintain versions of your blobs, all you need to do is enable versioning on the storage account. Once you enable that, anytime a blob is modified a new version of the blob will be created automatically for you by service. Please see this link to learn more about blob versioning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview.
2. **Manual versioning**: While automatic versioning is great but there could be many reasons why you would want to opt for manual versioning (e.g. you only want to version a few blobs and not all blobs, you are not using V2 Storage account etc.). If that's the case, then you can create a version of the blob by taking a snapshot of the blob before you update the blob. Snapshot creates a read-only copy of the blob at the point of time snapshot was taken. Please see this link to learn more about blob snapshot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/snapshots-overview.

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to enable versioning in the blob storage through the portal in the storage account.

[image]

- Just click on Disable it will take you to a different page and select enable version and click save
- Here after uploading the blob when you update the blob it will automatically trigger the creating of versions.

```
public static async Task UpdateVersionedBlobMetadata(BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient, 
                                                     string blobName)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the container.
        await blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        // Upload a block blob.
        BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);

        string blobContents = string.Format("Block blob created at {0}.", DateTime.Now);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(blobContents);

        string initalVersionId;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            Response<BlobContentInfo> uploadResponse = 
                await blockBlobClient.UploadAsync(stream, null, default);

            // Get the version ID for the current version.
            initalVersionId = uploadResponse.Value.VersionId;
        }

        // Update the blob's metadata to trigger the creation of a new version.
        Dictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "key", "value" },
            { "key1", "value1" }
        };

        Response<BlobInfo> metadataResponse = 
            await blockBlobClient.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);

        // Get the version ID for the new current version.
        string newVersionId = metadataResponse.Value.VersionId;

        // Request metadata on the previous version.
        BlockBlobClient initalVersionBlob = blockBlobClient.WithVersion(initalVersionId);
        Response<BlobProperties> propertiesResponse = await initalVersionBlob.GetPropertiesAsync();
        PrintMetadata(propertiesResponse);

        // Request metadata on the current version.
        BlockBlobClient newVersionBlob = blockBlobClient.WithVersion(newVersionId);
        Response<BlobProperties> newPropertiesResponse = await newVersionBlob.GetPropertiesAsync();
        PrintMetadata(newPropertiesResponse);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}

static void PrintMetadata(Response<BlobProperties> propertiesResponse)
{
    if (propertiesResponse.Value.Metadata.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Metadata values for version {0}:", propertiesResponse.Value.VersionId);
        foreach (var item in propertiesResponse.Value.Metadata)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key:{0}  Value:{1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Version {0} has no metadata.", propertiesResponse.Value.VersionId);
    }
}
```

The above code is from the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-enable?tabs=portal).